# StackExchange API authentication in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch, stackexchange-api

I'm trying to use the V2.2 of StackExchange API in Google Apps Script.

The problem comes in the last step of the explicit OAuth 2.0 flow, when I try to send the POST request to obtain the access token. I receive a 404 error, but making the same request manually (using postman extension) everything is ok.

To simplify the problem, if I send this POST request with no payload I receive the same 404

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://stackexchange.com/oauth/access_token", {
  method: 'post',
  muteHttpExceptions: true
});
Logger.log(response);
```

while in postman I receive this 400:

```
{
   "error": {
       "type": "invalid_request",
       "message": "client_id not provided"
   }
}
```

I guess this will be a problem with UrlFetchApp, but does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related with the Origin header.

You cannot remove from the header directly but you can perform the call via a proxy :)

Answer (score 0):

You need  to provide the data for the post by adding an 'option' object to the call.
For example:

```
var options = { "method" : "post", "payload" : payload };
UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://stackexchange.com/oauth/access_token", options);
```

Btw, have you tried you use the OAuth that UrlFetch got: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#addOAuthService(String) - It might be better way.

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same error. I don't use OAuthConfig because it doesn't work with APIs that use OAuth2. I use an adaptation of  [this library](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2) but it fails in this step.